# UIView auto layout slide in screen or out of screen animation

Tags: ios, autolayout, uiviewanimation

I can't figured it out how to do slide in/ out animation with auto layout.

I add constraints like this:

```
NSDictionary *viewsDic = @{@"tmpView" : tmpView};
[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[tmpView]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:viewsDic]];
[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[tmpView]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:viewsDic]];

[UIView animateWithDuration:.4 animations:^{
        [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
    }];
```

but this animates to grow from 0,0 position. how to achieve slide in/out animation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I understand, you need to get shift-effect. If my assumption is right, you need to manage horizontal or vertical padding manually during animation. And you need to get the reference on horizontal/vertical constraint:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSLayoutConstraint *topPadding;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSLayoutConstraint *heightConstraint;
```

Adding a constraint with initial value so that `tmpView` is out of visible part of its superview:

```
self.heightConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:tmpView
                                               attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                               relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                  toItem:nil
                                               attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute
                                              multiplier:1.0
                                                constant:0.0];

self.topPadding = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:tmpView
                                           attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                           relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                              toItem:self.view
                                           attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                          multiplier:1.0
                                            constant:self.view.bounds.size.height];

[self.view addConstraint:self.topPadding];
[self.view addConstraint:self.heightConstraint];
```

Then we need simply to show `tmpView` with animation:

```
 [self.view layoutIfNeeded];

 [UIView animateWithDuration:.4 animations:^{
    self.topPadding.constant = 0.0;
    self.heightConstraint.constant = self.view.bounds.size.height;

    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
}];
```

Whit this example tmpView appears from the bottom.
Please ensure that `self.topPadding` won't conflict with other you constraints

To hide the view you can use something like this:

```
 [self.view layoutIfNeeded];

 [UIView animateWithDuration:.4 animations:^{
    self.topPadding.constant = self.superview.bounds.size.height;

    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
}];
```

UPD.: Sometimes you also need to add hight constraints as well. Added use of `self.heightConstraint` in my example

UPD.: You still need horizontal constraints.
Please leave these lines:

```
NSDictionary *viewsDic = @{@"tmpView" : tmpView};
[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[tmpView]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:viewsDic]];
```

Comment: adding this constraint only, wont draw the view properly. i tried also adding my own constraint before animation. but it didn't work :(

Comment: Updated my answer, maybe it will be helpful. Note, you have to remove your previous vertical constraints

Comment: thanks for helping. but it does now zoom from the right of the screen.

Comment: try to add `[self.view layoutIfNeeded];` and `[tmpView layoutIfNeeded];` before and inside animation block

Comment: So, how would you dismiss this view then ?